# When merging Dataframes on a common column like ID (primary key),how do you handle data that appears more than once for a single ID, in the second df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

So I have two dfs.

DF1

```
Superhero ID    Superhero      City
212121          Spiderman      New york
364331          Ironman        New york
678523          Batman         Gotham
432432          Dr Strange     New york
665544          Thor           Asgard
123456          Superman       Metropolis
555555          Nightwing      Gotham
666666          Loki           Asgard
```

Df2

```
SID       Mission End date
665544    10/10/2020
665544    03/03/2021
212121    02/02/2021
665544    05/12/2020
212121    15/07/2021
123456    03/06/2021
666666    12/10/2021
```

I need to create a new df that summarizes how many heroes are in each city and in which quarter will their missions be complete. I'll be able to match the superhero (and their city) in df1 to the mission end date via their Superhero ID or SID in Df2 ('Superhero Id'=='SID'). Superhero IDs appear only once in Df1 but can appear multiple times in DF2.

Ultimately I need a count for the total no. of heroes in the different cities (which I can do - see below) as well as how many heroes will be free per quarter.

These are the thresholds for the quarters

```
Quarter 1 – Apr, May, Jun
Quarter 2 – Jul, Aug, Sept
Quarter 3 – Oct, Nov, Dec
Quarter 4 – Jan, Feb, Mar
```

The following code tells me how many heroes are in each city:

```
df_Count = pd.DataFrame(df1.City.value_counts().reset_index())
```

Which produces:

```
 City       Count
New york     3
Gotham       2
Asgard       2
Metropolis   1
```

I can also convert the dates into datetime format via the following operation:

```
#Convert to datetime series
Df2['Mission End date'] = pd.to_datetime('Df2['Mission End date']')
```

**Ultimately I need a new df that looks like this**

```
     City      Total Count    No. of heroes free in Q3    No. of heroes free in Q4   Free in Q1 2021+
    New york       3               2                           0                           1
    Gotham         2               2                           2                           0
    Asgard         2               1                           2                           0
    Metropolis     1               0                           0                           1
```

If anyone can help me create the appropriate quarters and be able to sort them into the appropriate columns I'd be extremely grateful. I'd also like a way to handle heroes having multiple mission end dates. I can't ignore them I need to still count them. I suspect I'll need to create a custom function which I can than apply to each row via the apply() method and a lambda expression. This issue has been a pain for a while now so I'd appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

After merging your dataframe with

```
 df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Superhero ID', right_on='SID')
```

And converting your date column to pd.datetime format

```
df.assign(missing_end_date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['Missing End Date']))
```

You can create two columns; one to extract the quarter and one to extract the year of the newly created datetime column

```
df.assign(quarter_end_date=lambda x: x.missing_end_date.dt.quarter)
  .assign(year_end_date=lambda x: x.missing_end_date.dt.year)
```

And combine them into a column that shows the quarter in a format Qx, yyyy

```
df.assign(quarter_year_end=lambda x: f"Q{int(x.quarter_end_date)}, {int(x.year_end_date)}")
```

Finally groupby the city and quarter, count the number of superheros and pivot the dataframe to get your desired result

```
df.groupby(['City', 'quarter_year_end'])
.count()
.reset_index()
.pivot(index='City', columns='quarter_year_end', values='Superhero')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Rick. Just wanted to clarify that data that repeats itself in df2 (ie SID) will still appear in the final df using your solution? Thanks so much for the work you’ve put into this :)

Comment: Yes. When merging two Pandas dataframes with .merge(), Pandas uses inner join by default, this will preserve all rows with IDs that appear in both dataframes, even if one of the dataframes has duplicate IDs. You can also specify to perform a 'left' join (preserve all IDs from the first mentioned dataframe), or a 'right' join (preserve all IDs from the second mentioned dataframe.